# zero padding regex dependent on length of digits

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a field which contains two charecters, some digits and potentially a single letter. For example

```
QU1Y
ZL002
FX16
TD8
BF007P
VV1395
HM18743
JK0001
```

I would like to consistently return all letters in their original position, but digits as follows.

for 1 to 3 digits : 
return all digits OR the digits left padded with zeros

For 4 or more digits :
it must not begin with a zero and return the 4 first digits OR if the first is a zero then truncate to three digits

example from the data above

```
QU001Y
ZL002
FX016
TD008
BF007P
VV1395
HM1874
JK001
```

The implementation will be in R but I'm interested in a straight regex solution, I'll work out the R side of things. It may not be possible in straight regex which is why I can't get my head round it.

This identifies the correct ones, but I'm hoping to correct those which are not
right.

```
"[A-Z]{2}[1-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[F,Y,P]{0,1}"
```

For the curious, they are flight numbers but entered by a human. Hence the variety...

Comment: You won't be able to solve it without a bit of code. Use `gsubfn` once you are sure you know the right pattern to match the strings where modification is required.

Comment: If the first two letters must exist, use `gsubfn('^[A-Z]{2}\\K0*(\\d{1,4})\\d*', ~ sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(x)), l, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: fred <- gsubfn("^[A-Z]{2}\\K0*(\\d{1,4})\\d*",
+                                     ~ sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(x)),
+                                     preactorDF[["Flight No"]],
+                                     perl = TRUE)
Error: is.character(x) is not TRUE

Comment: Please update the post with what your `preactorDF[["Flight No"]]` is, use `dput`.

Comment: The preactorDF has 1.3 million records. dput would be massive.

Comment: Try `dput(head(preactorDF,10))`

Comment: `dput(head(preactorDF[["Flight No"]],10))
c("BA038", "BA038", "BA247", "BA247", "BA198", "BA238", "BA238", 
"BA057", "BA199", "BA199")'` but this is a small  selection and very tidy.  other rows have NA in which may be the problem.

Comment: I cannot help more if you keep the data to yourself. The comment above does not help. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181538/discussion-between-rj3838-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
> library(gsubfn)
> l <- c("QU1Y", "ZL002", "FX16", "TD8", "BF007P", "VV1395", "HM18743", "JK0001")
> gsubfn('^[A-Z]{2}\\K0*(\\d{1,4})\\d*', ~ sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(x)), l, perl=TRUE)
[1] "QU001Y" "ZL002"  "FX016"  "TD008"  "BF007P" "VV1395" "HM1874" "JK001"
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase letters
- `\\K` - the text matched so far is removed from the match
- `0*` -  0 or more zeros
- `(\\d{1,4})` - Capturing group 1: one to four digits
- `\\d*` - 0+ digits.

Group 1 is  passed to the callback function where `sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(x))` pads the value with the necessary amount of digits.

Comment: @rj3838 Provide your input data in the question body.

Comment: I have errors `fred <- gsubfn("^[A-Z]{2}\\K0*(\\d{1,4})\\d*",
+                                     ~ sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(x)),
+                                     preactorDF[["Flight No"]],
+                                     perl = TRUE)
Error: is.character(x) is not TRUE' My source is 1324156 rows so a clue as to why may help.

Comment: @rj3838 I cannot help you with that since you have not provided reproducible code, the solution above works well with the strings you posted.